# How do I refresh the custom claims when its set in a google cloud function?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to set custom claims in a google function in firebase. Here is the code I have.

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid,{
                activeNetworkProfile: networkProfile,
                activeCompanyProfile: companyProfile,
                activeUserProfile: profiles[0]
            });
```

On the client side I have the following:

```
public updateProfiles(){
    return this.afAuth.idToken.pipe(
      switchMap(idToken => this.httpClient.post<any>('https://us-central1-company-database.cloudfunctions.net/updateProfiles',{
        "token": idToken,
        "np":"hzlNpVEdwqOKRTcsdfPG",
        "cp":"D7nKYrS235A9vnvfB9oD"
      }))
    );
  }
```

Then to test of the changes have been made:

```
 public validateToken(){
    return this.afAuth.idToken.pipe(
      switchMap(idToken => this.httpClient.post<any>('https://us-central1-company-database.cloudfunctions.net/validateToken',{
        "token": idToken
      }))
    );
  }
```

and on the server I have the following:

```
 export const validateToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, () => {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        let token = req.body.token;
        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token).then(decodedToken=>{
        res.status(200).send(decodedToken);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            res.status(401).send(error.message);
        });
    });
 });
```

I do not get the claims in the response. I have tried forcing the update in angularfire2 by setting the paramter to true

```
public getToken(){
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);
  }
```

but this didnt change anything if anything it caused firebase token update to go into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix by adding the following code after setting the claims.

```
 const metadataRef = admin.database().ref("metadata/" + user.uid);
 return metadataRef.set({refreshTime: new Date().getTime()});
```